# How to access UIViewController's varaibles inside "func applicationWillResignActive"? Swift, iOS xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have my UIViewController class set up like this :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var currentTask: NSURLSessionTask?

    ...

}
```

If the user presses Home button, I want to do

```
self.currentTask.cancel()
```

But how can I access this variable from AppDelegate.swift?

```
func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {

}
```

Answer (score 9):

in viewDidLoad() inside UIViewController class, add

```
    // Add UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification observer
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self,
        selector: "resigningActive",
        name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification,
        object: nil
    )
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self,
        selector: "becomeActive",
        name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification,
        object: nil
    )
```

for Swift 4, iOS 11, use this:

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    self, 
    selector: #selector(ViewController.resigningActive), 
    name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive, 
    object: nil)

 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    self, 
    selector: #selector(ViewController.becomeActive), 
    name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, 
    object: nil)
```

Finally add these two functions to your view controller:

```
@objc fileprivate func resigningActive() {
    print("== resigningActive ==")
}

@objc fileprivate func becomeActive() {
    print("== becomeActive ==")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For swift 4 and above you can use

```
UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification
```

and

```
UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification
```

for notification name.