# How can I detect if the notification center was opened

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocos2d-x, ios10, cocos2d-x-3.0

In a cocos2dx project, on iOS 10 devices, when the notification center is swiped down then up, a huge frame rate drop happens. As a result, when the animations resume ui elements whose motion depends on the delta t are moved to invalid positions. It looks to me that the OS is putting the app in some kind of a background mode but the `applicationDidEnterBackground` is not called.
Is there a way to receive an event when the notification center is swiped down/up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
applicationWillResignActive(_:)
```

The above delegate gets called when ur app leaves foreground. This is the same delegate that gets called when ur app momentarily looses focus like on receiving call etc.

You can use

```
applicationWillEnterForeground(_:)
```

to figure out when ur app regains the focus.

read : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate

As these delegates are called on App's `UIApplicationDelegate` which is typically ur appDelegate file and most of the times you would like to get notified of these events in individual ViewControllers rather than in AppDelegate you can always use `NotificationCenter` and add observer for `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification`

read : [How to access UIViewController's varaibles inside "func applicationWillResignActive"? Swift, iOS xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31375593/how-to-access-uiviewcontrollers-varaibles-inside-func-applicationwillresignact)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
So `applicationWillResignActive` is definitely called when the notification center is swiped down on iOS10?

Comment: @vahagn : Logically yes, I don't think anything specifically changed in iOS 10. I have used these to handle the device recieving voice call scenario. So should work with this as well

Comment: @vahagn : read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060066/sleep-mode-vs-notification-center-open this clearly mentions that applicationWillResignActive gets called on Notification Center pull down